# SQL Server : Windows Authetication working from Management Studio not from Apache

Tags: php, sql-server

My application (PHP, Codeignitor) is trying to connect to SQL Server 2016 via Windows Authentication.

Getting this error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456
> [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Login failed for user 'AAA\abcd'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'AAA\abcd'.
> ) )

This same windows account credentials when passed to SQL Server Management tool, is working fine.

Also when I try to connect to SQL Server with sql server user account, then also its working fine.

What am i missing?

Comment: What is your connection string and which library do you use?

Comment: I have not set connection string. I am using codeignitor and it has database config file, so I have added hostname, username, password and db name

Comment: What should be the connection string? I mean we can set connection string and then leave other db configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to SQL Server using windows authentication, just leave username and password empty. If you set username and password, then SQL authentication will be used.

When windows authentication is used, the Web server's process identity is used to connect to the server. 
That's why you can connect to the server with SQL Server Management Studio (authenticated with your windows credentials), but your script fails.

If you have PHP Driver for SQL Server, you may try this script to see under which account your script is executed.

```
<?php
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$cinfo = array(
    "Database"=>'master'
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT CONVERT(varchar(32), SUSER_SNAME())";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
echo "Login name: ".$row[0];

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```